# Docker echo to /etc/hosts not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN touch /tmp/foo
RUN echo 'bar' > /tmp/foo

RUN echo '192.168.99.100 foo' >> /etc/hosts

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

Inside the container:

```
root@47040a03cbc1:/# cat /tmp/foo 
bar
root@47040a03cbc1:/# cat /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.4  47040a03cbc1
```

Why does the first *echo* to `/tmp/foo` works but the second to `/etc/hosts` doesn't?

Comment: As an aside, as per Dockerfile best practises, get into the habit of chaining your statements into a single RUN, like so: _RUN touch /tmp/foo && echo 'bar' >/tmp/foo && echo '192.168.99.100 foo >> /etc/hosts_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker manages /etc/hosts. It does this to make container linking work. You can ask docker to append to the hosts file when starting the container with

```
docker run -it --add-host foo:192.168.99.100
```

Answer (score 2):

If use docker composer:

```
  extra_hosts:
 - "foo:192.168.99.100"
 - "bar:192.168.99.101"
```

Comment: Cheers, I had forgotten about this option